# Iterating through owned ec2.snapshots

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Im trying to print out every snapshot that hasn't got the specific Tag "CostReference" inside my aws account.

To Iterate through the snapshots I'm using:

```
    for snapshot in snapshots:

    if(not costreferencetag_isset_snapshot(snapshot)):
        print("[SNAPSHOT] " + str(snapshot))
        print("[INFO]: No CostReferenceTag!! \n")
        missingtagginginfo = missingtagginginfo + str(snapshot) + ": No CostReferenceTag\n"
        count_snapshot += 1
        continue
    else:
        costreference_snapshot = get_costreference_snapshot(snapshot)

        if costreference_snapshot not in managedpsp:
            print("[SNAPSHOT] " + str(snapshot))
            print("[INFO]: The PSP: " + costreference_snapshot + " of: " + str(snapshot) + " is WRONG! \n")
            missingtagginginfo = missingtagginginfo + str(snapshot) + " " + costreference_snapshot + ": Wrong PSP\n"
            count_snapshot += 1
print(count_snapshot)
```

So far so good the code is working, but I'm also getting the public Snapshots that are owned by amazon, wich have no relevance for me.

Is there any way to filter those public snapshots?

Greets

Code for the other functions:

```
def costreference_isset(instance):
#Searching for Instance without CostReference-tags
if instance.tags is None:
    print("[INFO]: No Tags have been set yet:")
    return(False)

#Searching for CostReference-tags
for t in instance.tags:
    if t['Key'] == 'CostReference':
        return(True)
return(False)

def get_costreferencetag(instance):

for t in instance.tags:
    if t['Key'] == "CostReference":
        return(str(t['Value']))

return(False)
```

managedpsp is a list with valid Costreference - tags

Answer (score 0):

Try using the filter `owner-id` with your own account number.

Check here for the CLI reference: [describe-snapshots — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-snapshots.html#options)

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with:

```
    for snapshot in snapshots.filter(OwnerIds= ['self']):

    if(not costreferencetag_isset_snapshot(snapshot)):
        print("[SNAPSHOT] " + str(snapshot))
        print("[INFO]: No CostReferenceTag!! \n")
        missingtagginginfo = missingtagginginfo + str(snapshot) + ": No CostReferenceTag\n"
        count_snapshot += 1
        continue
    else:
        costreference_snapshot = get_costreference_snapshot(snapshot)

        if costreference_snapshot not in managedpsp:
            print("[SNAPSHOT] " + str(snapshot))
            print("[INFO]: The PSP: " + costreference_snapshot + " of: " + str(snapshot) + " is WRONG! \n")
            missingtagginginfo = missingtagginginfo + str(snapshot) + " " + costreference_snapshot + ": Wrong PSP\n"
            count_snapshot += 1
print(count_snapshot)
```